# Symfony 4 - leftJoin tables with doctrine annotations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to join two tables, `categories` and `news`.
`category_id` is the foreign key generated by doctrine on `news` table.
 Everything works perfectly!!!... Until I **deliberately** modify a foreign key from 2 to 911 as you would see.

[image: Table news screenshot]

After this **logicaly** the jointure will break on Football news as thrown by Symfony as you can see.

[image: Symfony Exception screenshot]

So I assume leftJoin my tables would solve the issue

Comment: you should look at the `category` table for a row with id `911`

Comment: For sure but with some **left jointure** I think the issue would(should) be solved by returning `null` as `category` found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. Here was my annotation

```
**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="news")
 */
```

And I added some new property on my relation `fetch="EAGER"` so it now looks like this

```
 **
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", fetch="EAGER", inversedBy="news")
 */
```